# rsync "failed to set times on "XYZ": No such files or directory (2)

Tags: backup, rsync, nas

I have a Dlink NAS (dns-323) in RAID1 that I use to backup family photos, videos and some other data.  I also manually rsync to a dedicated backup drive on a little Atom Linux box whenever we add a lot of new files to the NAS.  I finally lost a drive on the NAS and through a misstep of my own, also lost the entire volume.  No problem, that's what the backup drive is for.  I used the same rsync command in reverse to restore files to the NAS after I replaced the bad drive and created a new RAID volume.  This worked well, except that after the command finished, I noticed that it did not preserve timestamps.  Timestamps were preserved in the NAS->backup direction, but not the backup->NAS direction.

I run the rsync command on the Atom Linux box with these options (this does preserve timestamps):

```
rsync --archive --human-readable --inplace --numeric-ids --delete /mnt/dns-323 /mnt/dlink_backup --progress --verbose --itemize-changes
```

The reverse command to restore the volume from the backup (which did not preserve timestamps) is very similar:

```
rsync --archive --human-readable --inplace --numeric-ids --delete /mnt/dlink_backup/dns-323/ /mnt/dns-323/ --progress --verbose --itemize-changes
```

which actually restores the files, but gives many errors like:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/mnt/dns-323/Rich/Code/.emacs": No such file or directory (2)
```

I've been googling most of the afternoon and trying different things, but so far haven't solved my problem.  I used the 'touch' command to successfully modify the times of one or two files on the NAS, just to prove that it can be done since I believe that is one thing that rsync must do.  I've tried doing this as my user and as root.  By this I mean that I've run `sudo rsync .....` as well as `rsync --rsync-path='/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/rsync' .....` where ..... is all of the previously mentioned parameters.  My `/etc/fstab` has these entries for the NAS and the backup drive, respectively:

```
# the dns-323
//192.168.1.202/Volume_1 /mnt/dns-323 cifs guest,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
# the dlink_backup drive
/dev/sdb /mnt/dlink_backup ext3 defaults 0 0
```

It's not absolutely critical to preserve timestamps if it just plain can't be done, but it seems like it should be possible - I'm just stumped.

Thanks in advance.  Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've earned my "tumbleweed" badge as a result of this one.  *pats self on back*

What I've learned:

**My solution**:

1) Removed the left hard drive from the dns-323, which is half of the RAID1 volume.

2) Mounted (ext3) this drive using a USB-to-SATA adapter to the machine where I run rsync.

3) Performed the rsync command for the restore outlined above.  I removed the --delete option which really shouldn't be there and I added the option --size-only.  The size-only option made it so that timestamps were essentially the only thing that got restored, since files had already restored properly.

4) Unmounted the left drive from the Atom machine and returned that drive to the dns-323, while also removing the right drive.  The right drive needs to be removed so that the dns-323 recognizes that the RAID volume is degraded.

5) Re-add the right drive to the dns-323 and tell it to rebuild the RAID volume.

6) All timestamps are now good.

**A possible alternate solution:**

I've read enough about rsync and NFS/Samba/cifs now to understand that this problem is likely related to permissions on the NFS server (dns-323).  Internally, the user/group ids in the dns-323 are 501/501.  No permutation of how I mounted the dns-323 on the Atom box would allow rsync to properly set timestamps.  I do believe that changing my user account on the Atom box to have uid/gid of 501/501 would have worked, though.  My user had the default 1000/1000 and root had 0/0 IIRC.